# Neither MS Access nor SQL maintain a Vlookup function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with an ID like below:-
Unit| Function | OrgID
000| 000 | 21

I have another table:-
Unit | Function | Subfunction | Level 4 | Level 5
01| 54| 65 | 21 | 96

I want to update the first table with the values (Unit, Function) from the second table. However the OrgID can in any field within unit, function, subfunction, level 4, level 5. So i cannot do a join on a specific column and use an update and it won't always be the same column.

Any one have any suggestions?

Thanks,

Vin

Comment: Please edit title as neither MS Access nor SQL maintain a Vlookup function, no doubt borrowed from Excel. And even then the Excel function does not update data with it.

Comment: I think you misread my last comment. I did not intend for you to re-title verbatim but change it to reflect your need without references to non-existing methods like VLookup(). Something like *SQL update between tables in MS Access* or *Many-to-many value update between tables*.

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly you need a primary key and foreign key, even if you use vlookup (excel)

Table A
Unit
Function
OrgID

Table B
Unit
Function
Subfunction
Level 4
Level 5

UPDATE Table A SET UNIT = COALESCE(T1.Unit, T2, UNit...)
FROM Table A AS T0
LEFT JOIN Table B AS T1 ON T0.OrgID = T1.Unit
LEFT JOIN Table C AS T2 ON T0.OrgID = T2.Function
.... and so on

The syntax might need some more adjustment, but I hope you got the idea :-)

Comment: And one remark  - from performance pov is quite slow but there are different ways to right the update command :)

Comment: Access doesn't have `COALESCE` before 2013 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj249645.aspx), `NZ` may help.

Comment: You have Nz function - can work with that also, I thing there is some IIF or case